# Где хранить состояние расширения Chrome?

Tags: chrome-extension

Если не использовать cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать localStorage API.

Запись:
`localStorage["setting"] = value;`

Чтение:
`value = localStorage["setting"];`

Answer (score 8):

[Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/storage.html) - с доступом из любого скрипта расширения (без пересылок сообщений между background и injected js).

**`chrome.storage.local`** - для локального хранения:

**запись**:

```
var a = {}; 
a["имя_ключа1"] = "Значение1"; 
a["имя_ключа2"] = "Значение2"; 
chrome.storage.local.set(a);
```

**чтение**:

```
var a = ["имя_ключа1", "имя_ключа2"]; 
chrome.storage.local.get(a, function(b) { 
    var result1 = b["имя_ключа1"]; 
    var result2 = b["имя_ключа2"] 
});
```

---

**`chrome.storage.sync`** - для синхронизированного хранения данных:

**запись**:

```
var a = {};
a["имя_ключа1"] = "Значение1";
a[имя_ключа2] = "Значение2";
chrome.storage.sync.set(a);
```

**чтение**:

```
var a = ["имя_ключа1", "имя_ключа2"];
chrome.storage.sync.get(a, function(b) { 
    var result1 = b["имя_ключа1"], 
    var result2 = b["имя_ключа2"]
});
```